# Ignore certain dotfiles from backup

Tags: nautilus, backup

When using the packaged Ubuntu Backup preferences pane, there is an option to ignore folders.

Traditionally when using a nautilus based File dialogue, you could press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide/show dotfiles, or hidden files in the unix directory structure.

This does not appear to be the case when working with the backup tool ignore path dialogue box. If I wanted to add a specific dotfile path for backup to safely ignore, where would I place that configuration value?

[image: Backup Dialogue]
[image: File Chooser Dialogue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current way is certainly a good one. Selecting the hidden folders in the Duplicity GUI does work well.

To do so:

1. In the "Choose Folders" menu, go to your HOME folder. "Smart Folders" (like Recently Used) don't have dotfiles in it (typically).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden folders/files.
3. Ctrl-Click select all of the hidden folders/files you DON'T want to back up.
4. ???
5. Profit.

Of course, you can also run a `cp` command on a Cron task that copies all of the folders except the ones you want to exclude. Keeping with duplicity though, your GUI way is good.

Just remember to attach the backup media regularly so you don't get flooded with "Backup Delayed" notifications.